# Getting answer of method to two decimal places

Tags: java, methods

I am using the code below to get the answer of a method i created into two decomal places. But when I do this and complile i get an error saying identifier expected. 2 error come up one pointing at the 2 and the other just before. what is my problem?

```
  import java.text.NumberFormat;

  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
 nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

Comment: Is this code inside of a method? Is that method inside of a class?

Comment: What you've shown is correct, assuming that the lines aren't all together (`import` statements must be outside of any class).

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I declare it outside the method but use it inside. There is no main in my code. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @user2140783: A `main` is only required in a class if that is the main class of a program being run via the `java` command-line tool. The absense of `main` will not cause an `Identifier expected` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've shown is correct, assuming that the lines aren't all together (`import` statements must be outside of any class). So for instance, this is valid:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

class MyClass {

    void someMethod() {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        // ...
    }
}
```

...but those lines together as shown in your question are not.

If that's not it, you said that the error seems to focus on the `2`. Sometimes when we see questions like this here on SO, it's because some zero-width or space-like special character has accidentally ended up in the source. So it may be that if you delete that line and retype it, you'll wipe out the offending character. (It's actually surprising how often that comes up.)

Comment: @user2140783: Don't know what else to tell you. If I copy the above and paste it into a `MyClass.java` file, it compiles just fine. So there must be *something* lurking in the source that you're not seeing (or inadvertently not showing us).

Answer (score -1):

You can write a general purpose function as follows:

```
public static double round(double inputNumber, int fractionDigits, int roundingMode) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(inputNumber);
        BigDecimal rounded = bigDecimal.setScale(fractionDigits, roundingMode);
        return rounded.doubleValue();
}
```

Please find below the sample test results:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class RoundHelper {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(RoundHelper.round(123.98980, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
        System.out.println(RoundHelper.round(123.98000, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
        System.out.println(RoundHelper.round(123.98000, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
        System.out.println(RoundHelper.round(123.55087, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
        System.out.println(RoundHelper.round(123.14000, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }

    public static double round(double inputNumber, int fractionDigits, int roundingMode) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(inputNumber);
        BigDecimal rounded = bigDecimal.setScale(fractionDigits, roundingMode);
        return rounded.doubleValue();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
123.99
123.98
123.98
123.55
123.14
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question the OP has asked, which is why perfectly valid code won't compile. (The question isn't terribly clear.)

Comment: It also doesn't work. Test the result % 0.01 it for all the values between .01 and .99 and you will get a nasty shock. It is non-zero in over 90% of cases, and it gets worse as you increase the precision.